# ALTER TABLE with a default: SQL Server vs Oracle

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

We have some tables in an Oracle database with several million rows. When we alter one of these tables to add a new column, we specify a default. This is very slow to run as Oracle has to update all existing rows with the default. The solution is to ensure the column is defined as NOT NULL because then Oracle (recent versions only) will not update all existing rows with the default - the subsequent presence of a null in one of these columns tells Oracle that it requires a default and it will provide the default on the fly.

My question is regarding SQL Server: does it exhibit similar behaviour when adding a column and providing a default? If not, are there any best practices in efficiently adding new columns with default values, and are there any advantages in defining a column as NOT NULL?

Comment: are you saying that Oracle allows adding columns with NOT NULL and not providing a default value?

Comment: I don't think Oracle allows that. The point I was trying to make was that NOT NULL combined with a default is very efficient, whereas a default without NOT NULL isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to SQL Server 2012 adding a NULLable column w/o default was very vast, but adding a DEFAULT contraint would be slow, as every row has to be updated. Since SQL Server 2012 [adding a DEFAULT is also fast, a metadata only operation](http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/), when possible.